# If a sequence {$f_n$} pointwise convergent on a finite set $D$ which is a subset of $\mathbb R$.Then can we say that the convergence is uniform?

Tags: real-analysis

If a sequence {$f_n$} pointwise convergent on a finite set $D$ which is a subset of $\mathbb R$.Then can we say that the convergence is uniform?

If the answer is yes then I have some problem here:

Let us suppose that $D$={$0$,$1$} and $f_n(x)$=$x^n$ then
 $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} f_n(x)=f(x)$

where $f(x) = \begin{cases} 0 & \text{ if } x=0\\
1 & \text{ if  }x=1 \\
\end{cases}$

so $f_n(x)$ pointwise convergent on$D$.But if $M_n= \max(\{|f_n(x) - f(x)| \ \big| \ \ x \in D\})$ then $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} M_n=1$ from which I can say that $f_n(x)$ is not uniformly convergent on $D$.Am I right or wrong?somebody please help me.

Comment: Note that in the case where $D=\{0,1\}$ and $f_n(x)=x^n$ we have that $f_n(x)=x$ for all $x$, therefore $f(x)=x$ as well. If that's not uniform convergence, I don't know what is!

Comment: Pointwise convergence does not imply uniform convergence. Not even if you have pointwise convergence everywhere (like in your example).

Comment: @TedShifrin Ah yes, my bad.  On second thought it is easy to come up with a counterexample when the set is compact, e.g. make $f_n$ equal to $1$ on a smaller and smaller set, but $0$ elsewhere.  However, it is certainly true when the set is finite, as in this question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, pointwise convergence on a finite set is uniform, because if $D = \{x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_k\}$, then for any $\epsilon > 0, \exists N_1, N_2, \ldots N_k \in \mathbb{N}$ such that
$$
|f_n(x_i) - f(x_i)| < \epsilon \quad\forall n\geq N_i
$$
So just take $N = \max\{N_1, N_2, \ldots, N_k\}$ and you see that
$$
\sup_{x\in D} |f_n(x) - f(x)| < \epsilon \quad\forall n\geq N
$$
In your example, as pointed out in the comments,
$$
f_n(x) = f(x) \quad\forall x\in D
$$
so $M_n = 0$ for all $n$. So, $M_n$ does not converge to $1$.